# Can a Type Derive from Itself?

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

When enforcing a Generic constraint

```
class GenericTest
{
    public void Sample<T>(T someValue) where T:Racer,new()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(someValue.Car);
    }
}
```

The Type T should be derived from the Base Type Racer (**Correct me if anything wrong**).

```
public class Racer
    {
        string name;
        string car;
        public Racer() { }
        public Racer(string name, string car)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.car = car;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
        }
        public string Car
        {
            get { return car; }
        }

    }
```

**In "Main()" I am executing as**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<Racer> rcr = new List<Racer>();
        rcr.Add(new Racer("James","Ferrari"));
        rcr.Add(new Racer("Azar","Bmw"));

        rcr.Sort(delegate(Racer a, Racer b)
        {return a.Name.CompareTo(b.Name); });

        GenericTest tst = new GenericTest();

        tst.Sample<Racer>(rcr[0]);

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

My Question is:

The constraint I implemented is `where T:Racer,new()`,So T should be derived from Racer.
But In Main() I am passing ( `tst.Sample<Racer>(rcr[0]);`)  the type `"Racer"`.The code is working.

**How come the Racer be derived from  Racer?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

> `where T : <base class name>`
>      The type argument must be or derive from the specified base class.

The point to note is *must be or derive from*. That means Racer *and* any class that derives from Racer.

Answer (score 7):

Derived from is the wrong way to read this constraint.  It is better read as "is convertible to".  This is why Racer works in this scenario.

**EDIT** : More details

This is covered in section 10.1.5 in the C# language spec.  ...

> If a constraint is a class type, an interface type, or a type parameter, that type specifies a minimal “base type” that every type argument used for that type parameter must support.

Comment: "is convertible to" is not *exactly* the best way to think of it.

Comment: @Martinho, agreed it's not perfect but it's a somewhat simplified way of thinking about it.

Answer (score 5):

What you are saying with that constraint is that the generic type argument `T` must be `Racer`, or a type that descends from `Racer`, not that it must be a descendant only.

Answer (score 1):

One way to look at it is  "Can an object of type **T** be assigned to a **Racer** reference?"

Answer (score 0):

The constraint would be true if the object that you are passing in can be cast to the type you've specified on the constraint.